# How to display default value in ion-select from one of the value obtained from locaStorage?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

```
<ion-select (ionChange)="onCountryChange($event)" [value]="country" formControlName ="country" name="country">
<ion-select-option [value]="country.name" *ngFor="let country of countryList">
{{country.name}} 
</ion-select-option>
</ion-select>
```

I need to set the default value from one the value obtained from local storage when the page loads

Comment: share code of when youre getting the data from LS and where you're initializing the `ReactiveForm`

Answer (score 1):

**For HTML**

```
<ion-select (ionChange)="onCountryChange($event)" [value]="selectedType" formControlName ="country" name="country">
<ion-select-option [value]="country.name" *ngFor="let country of countryList">
{{country.name}} 
</ion-select-option>
</ion-select>
```

**For TypeScript**

```
 this.selectedType = countryList.find(c => c.value == 'condition');
```